# CCID installation El Capitan

Tags: terminal, install, macos

I am trying to install [ccid-1.4.20](http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid.html#download) (command line) in an El Capitan enabled MacBook Air, but I am facing some issues. Instructions says that after uncompressing the file, in the generated folder I should do:

- ./MacOSX/configure
- make
- sudo make install

However at the end of the process, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: libusb.h not found, install libusb or use ./configure LIBUSB_CFLAGS=...
+ rm -f src/Info.plist
```

So I figured that `libusb` was missing.

I went to the `libusb` SourceForge project and downloaded [libusb-1.0.19](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/) and proceeded installing it. Here I get no error message(s).

Then I proceeded to retry installing, but I still have the same error. Any ideas?

---

Material and software used:

- MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013)
- 1.7 GHz Intel Core i7
- 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Mac OS X 10.11 Beta (15A278b)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to tell the `configure` of `ccid` where `libusb` can be found. Install `libusb` by downloading it and then running

```
./configure
make
sudo make
```

Then do the following for `ccid`:

```
.configure LIBUSB_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0 LIBUSB_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0"
```

(check the version number first).

Comment: Ok, gotcha (even though he said to have downloaded libusb) <br /> Regardless, thanks for the remarks, I'll do a better job next time!

Comment: This solution also works on Centos 7 :D

Comment: Good to hear mate :)

Comment: Ok, I still get the following error: `configure: error: install pcsc-lite 1.8.3 or later, or use ./configure PCSC_CFLAGS=...`

The command I issued was: `./configure LIBUSB_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0 LIBUSB_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -libusb-1.0.a"`

But in `/usr/local/lib` I have the following files:
`libusb-1.0.0.dylib`
`libusb-1.0.a`
`libusb-1.0.dylib -> libusb-1.0.0.dylib`
`libusb-1.0.la`

Answer (score 0):

Way too late, but there's an installer for this as well: https://github.com/martinpaljak/osx-ccid-installer